# Django python stack overflow somewhere in template

Tags: python, django, stack-overflow

I have a django app and I have made some changes to the tempate inheritance. I am getting stack overflow i dont know where from. Sometimes the page loads but while running im getting this error. Sometimes the error is throwed when server starts. The block renders a dashboard which is inside `dashboard.html` wrapped in a `content` `block`.

base.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,100,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

  <!-- All CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'app/css/navbar/navbar.css' %}">
</head>
<body>
  {% block content %}
  {% endblock content %}
</body>
</html>
```

```
ystem check identified no issues (0 silenced).
September 08, 2021 - 12:54:38
Django version 3.1.3, using settings 'auth.settings.development'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
Fatal Python error: _Py_CheckRecursiveCall: Cannot recover from stack overflow.
Python runtime state: initialized

Thread 0x00002910 (most recent call first):
  File "C:\Users\bratca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\socket.py", line 704 in readinto
  File "C:\Users\bratca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 182 in handle_one_request
  File "C:\Users\bratca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 172 in handle
  File "C:\Users\bratca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\socketserver.py", line 720 in __init__
  File "C:\Users\bratca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\socketserver.py", line 360 in finish_request
  File "C:\Users\bratca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\socketserver.py", line 650 in process_request_thread
  File "C:\Users\bratca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 888 in run
  File "C:\Users\bratca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 950 in _bootstrap_inner
  File "C:\Users\bratca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 908 in _bootstrap

Current thread 0x00000fe4 (most recent call first):
  File "C:\Users\bratca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 220 in wrapper
  File "C:\Users\bratca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 782 in __init__
  File "C:\Users\bratca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 641 in __init__
  File "C:\Users\bratca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 563 in compile_filter
  File "C:\Users\bratca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 1372 in url
  File "C:\Users\bratca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 476 in parse
  File "C:\Users\bratca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 213 in do_block
  File "C:\Users\bratca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 476 in parse
  File "C:\Users\bratca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 193 in compile_nodelist
  File "C:\Users\bratca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 155 in __init__
  File "C:\Users\bratca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\loaders\base.py", line 29 in get_template
  File "C:\Users\bratca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\engine.py", line 125 in find_template
  File "C:\Users\bratca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\engine.py", line 143 in get_template
  File "C:\Users\bratca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\engine.py", line 174 in select_template
  File "C:\Users\bratca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 180 in render
  File "C:\Users\bratca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 905 in render_annotated
  File "C:\Users\bratca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 938 in render
  File "C:\Users\bratca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\test\utils.py", line 96 in instrumented_test_render
  File "C:\Users\bratca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 150 in render
  File "C:\Users\bratca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 905 in render_annotated
  File "C:\Users\bratca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 938 in render
  File "C:\Users\bratca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\test\utils.py", line 96 in instrumented_test_render
  File "C:\Users\bratca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 172 in render
  File "C:\Users\bratca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 192 in render
  File "C:\Users\bratca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 905 in render_annotated
  File "C:\Users\bratca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 938 in render
  File "C:\Users\bratca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\test\utils.py", line 96 in instrumented_test_render
  File "C:\Users\bratca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 150 in render
  File "C:\Users\bratca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 905 in render_annotated
  File "C:\Users\bratca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 938 in render
  File "C:\Users\bratca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\test\utils.py", line 96 in instrumented_test_render
  File "C:\Users\bratca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 172 in render
  File "C:\Users\bratca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 192 in render
  File "C:\Users\bratca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 905 in render_annotated
  File "C:\Users\bratca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 938 in render
  File "C:\Users\bratca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\test\utils.py", line 96 in instrumented_test_render
  File "C:\Users\bratca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 150 in render
  File "C:\Users\bratca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 905 in render_annotated
  File "C:\Users\bratca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 938 in render
  File "C:\Users\bratca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\test\utils.py", line 96 in instrumented_test_render
  File "C:\Users\bratca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 172 in render
  File "C:\Users\bratca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 192 in render
  File "C:\Users\bratca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 905 in render_annotated
  File "C:\Users\bratca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 938 in render
  File "C:\Users\bratca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\test\utils.py", line 96 in instrumented_test_render
  File "C:\Users\bratca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 150 in render
  File "C:\Users\bratca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 905 in render_annotated
  File "C:\Users\bratca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 938 in render
  File "C:\Users\bratca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\test\utils.py", line 96 in instrumented_test_render
  File "C:\Users\bratca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 172 in render
  File "C:\Users\bratca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 192 in render
  File "C:\Users\bratca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 905 in render_annotated
  File "C:\Users\bratca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 938 in render
  File "C:\Users\bratca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\test\utils.py", line 96 in instrumented_test_render
  File "C:\Users\bratca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 150 in render
  File "C:\Users\bratca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 905 in render_annotated
  File "C:\Users\bratca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 938 in render
  File "C:\Users\bratca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\test\utils.py", line 96 in instrumented_test_render
  File "C:\Users\bratca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 172 in render
  File "C:\Users\bratca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 192 in render
  File "C:\Users\bratca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 905 in render_annotated
  File "C:\Users\bratca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 938 in render
  File "C:\Users\bratca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\test\utils.py", line 96 in instrumented_test_render
  File "C:\Users\bratca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 150 in render
  File "C:\Users\bratca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 905 in render_annotated
  File "C:\Users\bratca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 938 in render
  File "C:\Users\bratca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\test\utils.py", line 96 in instrumented_test_render
  File "C:\Users\bratca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 172 in render
  File "C:\Users\bratca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 192 in render
  File "C:\Users\bratca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 905 in render_annotated
  File "C:\Users\bratca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 938 in render
  File "C:\Users\bratca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\test\utils.py", line 96 in instrumented_test_render
  File "C:\Users\bratca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 150 in render
  File "C:\Users\bratca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 905 in render_annotated
  File "C:\Users\bratca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 938 in render
  File "C:\Users\bratca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\test\utils.py", line 96 in instrumented_test_render
  File "C:\Users\bratca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 172 in render
  File "C:\Users\bratca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 192 in render
  File "C:\Users\bratca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 905 in render_annotated
  File "C:\Users\bratca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 938 in render
  File "C:\Users\bratca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\test\utils.py", line 96 in instrumented_test_render
  File "C:\Users\bratca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 150 in render
  File "C:\Users\bratca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 905 in render_annotated
  File "C:\Users\bratca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 938 in render
  File "C:\Users\bratca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\test\utils.py", line 96 in instrumented_test_render
  File "C:\Users\bratca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 172 in render
  File "C:\Users\bratca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 192 in render
  File "C:\Users\bratca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 905 in render_annotated
  File "C:\Users\bratca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 938 in render
  File "C:\Users\bratca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\test\utils.py", line 96 in instrumented_test_render
  File "C:\Users\bratca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 150 in render
  File "C:\Users\bratca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 905 in render_annotated
  File "C:\Users\bratca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 938 in render
  File "C:\Users\bratca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\test\utils.py", line 96 in instrumented_test_render
  File "C:\Users\bratca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 172 in render
  File "C:\Users\bratca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 192 in render
  File "C:\Users\bratca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 905 in render_annotated
  File "C:\Users\bratca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 938 in render
  File "C:\Users\bratca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\test\utils.py", line 96 in instrumented_test_render
  File "C:\Users\bratca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 150 in render
  ...

Thread 0x00004dac (most recent call first):
  File "C:\Users\bratca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pymongo\periodic_executor.py", line 140 in _run
  File "C:\Users\bratca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 888 in run
  File "C:\Users\bratca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 950 in _bootstrap_inner
  File "C:\Users\bratca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 908 in _bootstrap

Thread 0x00003894 (most recent call first):
  File "C:\Users\bratca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pymongo\periodic_executor.py", line 140 in _run
  File "C:\Users\bratca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 888 in run
  File "C:\Users\bratca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 950 in _bootstrap_inner
  File "C:\Users\bratca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 908 in _bootstrap

Thread 0x000027fc (most recent call first):
  File "C:\Users\bratca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\selectors.py", line 315 in _select
  File "C:\Users\bratca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\selectors.py", line 324 in select
  File "C:\Users\bratca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\socketserver.py", line 232 in serve_forever
  File "C:\Users\bratca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 216 in run
  File "C:\Users\bratca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 139 in inner_run
  File "C:\Users\bratca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 53 in wrapper
  File "C:\Users\bratca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 888 in run
  File "C:\Users\bratca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 950 in _bootstrap_inner
  File "C:\Users\bratca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 908 in _bootstrap

Thread 0x00005730 (most recent call first):
  File "C:\Users\bratca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 370 in tick
  File "C:\Users\bratca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 320 in run_loop
  File "C:\Users\bratca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 314 in run
  File "C:\Users\bratca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 599 in start_django
  File "C:\Users\bratca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 614 in run_with_reloader
  File "C:\Users\bratca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 103 in run
  File "C:\Users\bratca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 96 in handle
  File "C:\Users\bratca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 371 in execute
  File "C:\Users\bratca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 61 in execute
  File "C:\Users\bratca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 330 in run_from_argv
  File "C:\Users\bratca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 395 in execute
  File "C:\Users\bratca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401 in execute_from_command_line
  File "D:AuthenticationProject\auth\manage.py", line 21 in main
  File "D:AuthenticationProject\auth\manage.py", line 26 in <module>
DEBUG:asyncio:Using proactor: IocpProactor
```

dashboard.html

```
{% extends "app/base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
<div class="row mt-4">
    <div class="col-12">
        <div class="card border-secondary mb-3 text-center">
            <div class="">
                <table class="">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>IMAGE</th>
                            <th>NAME</th>
                            <th>ROOM</th>
                            <th>Entrance</th>
                            <th>Temperature</th>
                            <th>CREATED</th>
                            <th>NAME</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {% for row in records %}
                        <tr>
                            <td>

                            </td>
                            <td>{{ row.people_name }}</td>
                            <td>{{ row.room_name }}</td>
                            {% if row.entrance_type == 1 %}
                            <td><span class="label label-success label-rounded">IN</span></td>
                            {% else %}
                            <td><span class="label label-danger label-rounded">OUT</span></td>
                            {% endif %}
                            <td>{{ row.temperature }}&nbsp;&nbsp;°C</td>
                            <td class="">{{ row.create_time}}</td>
                        </tr>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            {% if is_paginated %}
            {% include 'app/pagination.html' with object=page_obj %}
            {% endif %}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

pagination.html

```
{% block pag %}

    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
        <ul class="pagination mx-auto">
            {% if object.has_previous %}
                <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?page=1">First</a></li>
                <li>
                    <a class="page-link" href="?page={{ object.previous_page_number }}" aria-label="Previous">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
                        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            {% endif %}

            {% for num in object.paginator.page_range %}
                {% if object.number == num %}
                    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?page={{ num }}">{{ num }}</a></li>
                {% elif num > object.number|add:'-3' and num < object.number|add:'3' %}
                    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?page={{ num }}">{{ num }}</a></li>
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}

            {% if object.has_next %}
                <li class="page-item">
                    <a class="page-link" href="?page={{ object.next_page_number }}" aria-label="Next">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
                        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link txt-oflo" href="?page={{ object.paginator.num_pages }}">Last</a></li>
            {% endif %}
        </ul>
    </div>

{% endblock pag %}
```

Comment: You show some parts which appear to be truncated (`// table`), what are their contents? Also you load some template tags `timetags`, are these custom template tags and are they thread safe?

Comment: I have removed the timetags and not using anything, same error

Comment: even if i comment the dashboard.html contents

Comment: Well what are the contents of that `// stuff` in the `head` tag of your `base.html`?

Comment: did you try removing parts of the template to identify which part is causing it?

Comment: yes, raw `base.html` without averything from `head` gives same error

Comment: Is your _removing_ actually commenting the code? And are those comments HTML comments or Django comments?

Comment: it was html commenting, it works now! thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using {% endblock %} instead of {% endblock content %} and {% endblock pag %}